# Emacs embedded in a Qt Application

Tags: qt, emacs, embed

I've tried to embed emacs in a Qt Application using `QX11EmbedContainer`, and works but with two important exception. First of all, here is the code:

```
#include <QX11EmbedWidget>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  QX11EmbedContainer container;
  container.show();
  container.resize(500, 500);

  QProcess* process = new QProcess(&container);
  QString executable("emacsclient");

  QStringList arguments;
  arguments << "--parent-id" << QString::number(container.winId());

  process->start(executable, arguments);

  int status = app.exec();

  process->close();

  return status;
}
```

And the compilation and execution line (and the previous thrown of the emacs server):

```
$ emacs -q --daemon &
// filtered output
$ g++ test.cpp -lQtGui -lQtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4
$ ./a.out
```

And finally, the result:

[image: Emacs client embedded in Qt]

But, when or if I try to write something in the minibuffer, the size of the widget is collapsed, and the focus is also lost:

[image: other capture]

If I make click in the (now shorter) widget, I can continue working with emacs without problems, but I should resize the window in order to emacs is expanded other time as originally.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 6):

Try using a layout.

[Here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/layout.html) is the Qt5 documentation on layout management.